# Prestige level reset to 0 in Modern Warfare 3?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I was *Prestige 17: Level 50*, playing Search & Destroy in a lobby. I left the game and the next thing I know I'm Prestige 0: Level 0. I played a couple of games of Team Deathmatch and now I'm *Prestige 0: Level 7*. It seems like my prestige was reset for some reason and it won't go back to 17.

I've lost only my prestige progress; All the titles and emblems I've unlocked are still intact. My player card is just like it was before. I have the previously unlocked custom classes although I had to get to lvl 4.

I have tried signing out/in of PSN, removing/re-inserting the game CD, turning my PS3 off/on but no dice so far.

I created a secondary account just to reach prestige master and now I'm back to square one. Is there anything I can do to get my Prestige levels back?

Proof: My PSN is **Jack-ThePwner**

Comment: Not quite but I've the answer

Comment: Jesus! It's not a duplicate. Prestige token has nothing to do with prestige level. And I can confirm my answer because recently my friend went through the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when you exit from a hacker lobby. *Server connection lost* in my case.  I regained my prestige roughly around lvl 50-60. Perhaps that's how much xp I needed to level up from 50 to 80 (where I left off). As for the stats, there's no good news.